# How to GROUP entries BY uninterrupted sequence?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  title character varying,
  load_sequence integer
);
```

and data

```
INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('A', 1);
INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('A', 2);
INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('A', 3);

INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('A', 6);

INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('B', 4);
INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('B', 5);

INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('B', 7);
INSERT INTO entries(title, load_sequence) VALUES ('B', 8);
```

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to write SQL that groups data by same `title` segments after ordering them by `load_sequence`.
I mean:

```
=# SELECT id, title, load_sequence FROM entries ORDER BY load_sequence;
 id | title | load_sequence 
----+-------+---------------
  9 | A     |             1
 10 | A     |             2
 11 | A     |             3
 13 | B     |             4
 14 | B     |             5
 12 | A     |             6
 15 | B     |             7
 16 | B     |             8
```

AND I want groups:

```
=# SELECT title, string_agg(id::text, ',' ORDER BY id) FROM entries ???????????;
```

so result would be:

```
 title | string_agg  
-------+-------------
 A     | 9,10,11
 B     | 13,14
 A     | 12
 B     | 15,16
```

Comment: Unfortunately questions like this are rare that include the table creation scripts plus runnable `INSERT` statements that setup the sample data. +1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT title, string_agg(id::text, ',' ORDER BY id)
FROM (
  SELECT id, title, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY load_sequence) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title 
                            ORDER BY load_sequence) AS grp
  FROM entries ) AS t
GROUP BY title, grp
```

Calculated `grp` field serves to identify slices of `title` records having consecutive `load_sequence` values. Using this field in the `GROUP BY` clause we can achieve the required aggregation over `id` values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08149/3)

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea.
With little modifications for my specific case it works finally.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you can use with `sum` as a window function running over a `lag`ged window for this.

The idea is that when you hit an edge/discontinuity you return 1, otherwise you return 0. You detect the discontinuities using the `lag` window function.

```
SELECT title, string_agg(id::text, ', ') FROM (
  SELECT 
   id, title, load_sequence,
   sum(title_changed) OVER (ORDER BY load_sequence) AS partition_no
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id, title, load_sequence,
      CASE WHEN title = lag(title, 1) OVER (ORDER BY load_sequence) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS title_changed FROM entries
  ) x
) y
GROUP BY partition_no, title;
```